# Trouble with seemingly extremely simple statistics question involving normal distribution and expectation.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, variance, expected-value

Say we have a random variable X which is distributed like such: X ~ N(1, 4).

A question asks me to calculate $E(X^2)$, which I thought would be straight forward. I use the formula for Variance: $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$. I plug in the values of $\sigma^2 = 16$ and $\mu = 1$ and achieve an answer of 17. The correct answer is given as 5 although. Why am I wrong here? Am I missing something incredibly simple? Thank you in advance

Comment: I expect it's notation.  While some people, like you, write $N(\mu, \sigma)$ perhaps your source writes $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (for instance, that's how [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) writes it).

Comment: Ok, thank you both for clarifying!

Comment: I second the above comment. Almost all sources that I have seen use the notation $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ to denote the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. This is perhaps because we usually use mean and covariance structure to specify a gaussian process (such as multivariate normal).